# How do I modify sliderInput in shiny so user can directly type in value?

Tags: r, visualization, shiny

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
              min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
  ),
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs))
  })
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have a simple app with a `sliderInput` with which the user can toggle and select the number of observations. Is there a way to modify this so that on top of this slider function, the user can enter in his/her desired number of observations into a box, and that input will be reflected in the resulting histogram? I want to user to have the flexibility of having the slider and also be able to input an exact value quickly without having to depend on the slider all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
            numericInput("obs_numeric", "Number of observations", min = 0, max = 500, value = 500),
            sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
                        min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
            ),
            plotOutput("distPlot")
    )

    # Server logic
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
            output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
                    hist(rnorm(input$obs))
            })
            observeEvent(input$obs, {
                    updateNumericInput(session, "obs_numeric", value = input$obs)
            })
            observeEvent(input$obs_numeric, {
                    updateSliderInput(session, "obs",
                                      value = input$obs_numeric)
            })
    }

    # Complete app with UI and server components
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When the user starts changing one of these values, It will eventually get into an infinite loop of actualizing both of these input values. I had a similar problem and I finally solved it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54635680/5127304